# Stored procedure called from C# executes 6 times longer than from SQL Management studio

Tags: linq, performance, t-sql

I have search stored procedure which is my performance bottleneck.

In order to get control about what is happened, I added logging for all parameters and also execution time in SP.

I noticed, that when I call SP from MIcrosoft SQL server management Studio execution time is 1.3-1.6 seconds, but when i call it from C#, it takes 6-8 secods (!!!)

```
Parameters                                                            | Time (ms)
"tb *"TreeType:259Parents:212fL:13;14fV:0;lcid:2057min:0max:10sort:-1 | 6406      
"tb *"TreeType:259Parents:212fL:13;14fV:0;lcid:2057min:0max:10sort:-1 | 1346
```

SP is called with LINQ. Login settings are same.
SP uses full text search

What could cause this?

Comment: I am not sure regarding Microsoft SQL caching system. Try to run stored procedure from management studio and then from C#. Will be results differs from current?

Comment: @Anton: I can get same results not depending of calls order. Actually, this is list is sorted by id desc, so latest request is last.

Comment: Do you tried to use `SqlCommand` instead of LINQ? You can use `Prepare` method additionally. Do you use local SQL Server? What data returns the stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to locate such issues, the best tool is SQL Profiler, which records the exact call to database.

For me the difference was with novalue passed by SQL sample, which was substituted by '' and null value passed by C#.